# How to rename a virtual machine in Azure portal?

Tags: azure

At https://portal.azure.com , in the **Browse All Resources** page, there is a **Name** column. How can I change the name of a resource?

I have been looking around, but I cannot find that option. Is it not allowed?

I already changed the Virtual Machine host name, but for consistency, I would like the **Name** matches the host name, otherwise I will always have to remember that *foo_x* virtual machine matches the machine with host name *foo_y* and with domain name *foo_z.cloudapp.net*.

Answer (score 3):

You can not change VM name in the portal as it is DNS name (i.e. *.cloudapp.net) which  belongs to the cloud service. If you want to change the DNS name, you'll need to delete the cloud service, recreate it using the new name, and then redeploy the VM inside of it(delete the VM while retaining all the Disks that were attached to it, then recreate the VM with the new name and reattach the Disks that were attached to the original VM).

Comment: My VM ended up with a very different and random name, because I picked an IDN DNS name. I do not want to change the DNS name, but I was wondering how to get a closer VM name to my DNS name.